# Get taxonomies (for custom post type) to use parent archive styling by default

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I just created a new custom post type called research.  I added three taxonomies, research field, author and publication. I then created archive-research.php and content-research.php to create a different style. I was under the impression that all the taxonomies from research would use this archive, so I was either wrong or I've screwed something up.  The whole point of the various taxonomies was to be able to create various listings I could add to the menu, but they all end up using the default archive.  The only way to use the custom archive is to visit mywebsite.com/research, but that shows everything. I know it's possible to create custom taxonomies templates as well, but is there is some way to have the taxonomies use their parent archive by default?

Anyway, here is the code I'm currently using, maybe I'm just missing something, I'm still rather new at wordpress.

```
function create_research_cpt() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Research', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Research', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'name_admin_bar' => __( 'Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'archives' => __( 'Research Archives', 'textdomain' ),
    'attributes' => __( 'Research Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Research:', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_items' => __( 'View Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
    'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
    'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
    'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list' => __( 'Research list', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Research list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
    'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter Research list', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label' => __( 'Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => __( 'Studies, Papers, Data & Research', 'textdomain' ),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
    'taxonomies' => array('field', 'authors', 'publications', ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'research', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_research_cpt', 0 );

function create_field_tax() {

$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Research Fields', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Research Field', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Research Fields', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Research Fields', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Research Field', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Research Field:', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Research Field', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Research Field', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Research Field', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Research Field Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Research Field', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
);
register_taxonomy( 'field', array('research', ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_field_tax' );


function create_author_tax() {

$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Authors', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Author', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Authors', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Authors', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Author', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Author:', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Author', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Author', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Author', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Author Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Author', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
);
register_taxonomy( 'author', array('research', ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_author_tax' );



function create_publication_tax() {

$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Publications', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Publication', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Publications', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Publications', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Publication', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Publication:', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Publication', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Publication', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Publication', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Publication Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Publication', 'textdomain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
);
register_taxonomy( 'publication', array('research', ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_publication_tax' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was under the impression that all the taxonomies from research would
>   use this archive

According to the [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types), yes, you can use *archive-research.php* to render the appropriate archive index page for the custom post type *research*. However, for the custom taxonomies, [you'd need *taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php*](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies). So:

- *taxonomy-field.php*
- *taxonomy-author.php*
- *taxonomy-publication.php*

Or, if you want **just one template**, then in *archive.php*, you can construct the Loop like this: (which is based on the *archive.php* template for [Twenty Seventeen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/) theme version 1.4)

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        if ( 'research' === get_post_type() ) {
            // Load template based on the Post Type.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'research' );
        } else {
            // Load template based on the Post Format.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
        }

    endwhile;

else :

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' );

endif; ?>
```

[EDIT] Referring to the following comment:

> It's just I want to use a different look for the research archives as
>   opposed to the blog, and didn't want to have to go through each
>   taxonomy

Add this to the theme's *functions.php* file:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function ( $template ) {
    if ( is_tax( array( 'field', 'author', 'publication' ) ) ) {
        return locate_template( 'archive-research.php' );
    }
    return $template;
} );
```

Comment: This example would change the formatting of an entry under research to be different than a regular post if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But it doesn't necessarily need to be. You can share the same formatting/styles if you want, but that's really up to you.

Comment: Ok, just checking.  That part is actually working the way I wanted it too.  Any entry under the post type research uses the formatting I want it to for a single entry. I just needed to add content-research.php in the template-parts dir.  It's just I want to use a different look for the research archives as opposed to the blog, and didn't want to have to go through each taxonomy, right now I have three, but could be needing to add more.

Comment: Perhaps the new code snippet I've just added to my answer can help you with that? That code snippet should make the custom taxonomies' archive pages use the *archive-research.php* template. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: You are my new hero